# How to write this condition using guard let

Tags: swift

I want this condition using `guard let`.

```
if (self.fromLocation == nil || self.toLocation == nil) && self.key.isEmpty {
    return
}
print("fromLocation and toLocation are not nil and key isn't empty")
```

Initially I had

```
guard let fromLoc = self.fromLocation, let toLoc = self.toLocation else {
    return
}
print(fromLoc,toLoc)
```

Now I need to continue even if one or both `self.fromLocation,self.toLocation` are nil only if `key.isEmpty` is `false`

The above `if` condition works. But how can I write this using `guard let`?

**Condition 1.** If key is empty both from and to should be not nil

**Condition 2.** If key is not empty from and to can be nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the equivalent `guard` statement:

```
guard (self.fromLocation != nil && self.toLocation != nil) || !self.key.isEmpty else {
    return
}
```

**Explanation:**

I arrived at this by taking the statement of when we want to `return`:

```
(self.fromLocation == nil || self.toLocation == nil) && self.key.isEmpty
```

and negating it to get when we want to stay:

```
!((self.fromLocation == nil || self.toLocation == nil) && self.key.isEmpty)
```

Applying De Morgan's law `!(A && B) <==> !A || !B`:

```
!(self.fromLocation == nil || self.toLocation == nil) || !self.key.isEmpty
```

and then applying De Morgan's law `!(A || B) <==> !A && !B`:

```
(!(self.fromLocation == nil) && !(self.toLocation) == nil) || !self.key.isEmpty
```

and then noting that `!(A == nil) <==> A != nil` gives us the final result:

```
(self.fromLocation != nil && self.toLocation != nil) || !self.key.isEmpty
```

---

**Note:**

You said you wanted to do this with `guard let`, but that doesn't make sense since you stated that you are willing to continue if one or both variables are `nil` as long as key is not empty, so it isn't possible to guarantee that the unwrapped variables will exist after the `guard` statement.

Comment: Wow, just wrote the same answer with De Morgan's law and saw yours later. +1

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation